# Get average of column separated by groups

Tags: mysql

So I have a query that produces a table like the below, without the avg column. I'm trying to figure out how to add the avg column. The average should be from the profit of all stores within that month. I'm assuming I need to use AVG with a group by clause but can't seem to get it right.

I thought I could use a subquery to just get the rows for each month and average that, however I don't always know the number of months that will be in the table.

```
| store_id | month   | profit | avg|
------------------------------------
| 01       | Jan     | 100    | 200|
| 02       | Jan     | 200    | 200|
| 03       | Jan     | 300    | 200|
| 01       | Feb     | 250    | 250|
| 02       | Feb     | 200    | 250|
| 03       | Feb     | 300    | 250|
| 01       | Mar     | 150    | 100|
| 02       | Mar     | 50     | 100|
| 03       | Mar     | 100    | 100|
```

Comment: Show your data/query by editing the question. Yes `store_id`,`month` needs to be your `GROUP BY` values. You shouldn't need a subquery. SQL returns results that exist in the database so missing months are omitted. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Why do you need to know the number of months? `SELECT month, AVG(profit) AS avg FROM yourTable GROUP BY month`

Comment: Join that subquery with the original query on the `month` column.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table to hold averages

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS average
    SELECT month, avg(profit) AS `average profit` FROM store
        GROUP BY month;
```

Then `join` (left, inner) based on `month`

```
SELECT store.*, average.`average profit` FROM store
    LEFT JOIN average USING (month);
```

Fiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8u6DKWA8BmQgDmZxePLubn/0

Output:

```
| store_id | month   | profit | average profit |
| 01       | Jan     | 100    | 200            |
| 02       | Jan     | 200    | 200            |
| 03       | Jan     | 300    | 200            |
| 01       | Feb     | 250    | 250            |
| 02       | Feb     | 200    | 250            |
| 03       | Feb     | 300    | 250            |
| 01       | Mar     | 150    | 100            |
| 02       | Mar     | 50     | 100            |
| 03       | Mar     | 100    | 100            |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using this query. `Select` statement inside a `Select` statement.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(profit)/COUNT(*) FROM tbl1 
WHERE t.`month`=tbl1.`month`) AS ave FROM tbl1 t;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT *, (SELECT AVG(profit) FROM tbl1 
WHERE t.`month`=tbl1.`month`) AS ave FROM tbl1 t;
```

**Result**

[image]